# How to store documents/images/video on a different server in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, installation, content-database

Currently I'm using SharePoint 2010. The sites and sub-sites are stored on the C drive. Since, this SharePoint site is going to have a large amount of documents, images, and videos I would like to store them on another drive. Is is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Sharepoint stores most things in the Database, not on the local drive.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the Database on another system drive?

Comment: If you did a single server installation, it would have installed SQLServer Express on your computer.  As part of this installation process, it should have asked you where you would like to install SQLExpress.  You could modify the content database and move it to another drive:

Detach the database, move the two files to the new location, and then reattach the database.

You will find this easier to do if you were to download and install the SQL Server Management Studio Express. Get a free copy here:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use Remote BLOB Storage to store your Documents, Images and Videos. Remote BLOB Storage is an Add-On to SQL Server 2008 that allows you to store binary files at a different location then the database:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx

You may also find this blog entry useful, as it contains screenshots and additional instructions:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=174

Pete